# Is there an easy way to work around the sign() function?

Tags: r

I have a function written that uses the sign() function to find which numbers are positive or negative in the given vector. I am wondering if there is an easy way to get a vector of characters (like + and -) without using the sign() function.

Comment: Can you include some data which demonstrates what you are trying to do?  Also, why not just use an inequality to check the sign?

Comment: Huh? I read this as you want to reimplement the sign function, which would seem to be a strange request. Am I reading this right? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can always use `ifelse`.

Comment: Or `sub("1", "+", sub("-1", "-", sign(x)))`.

Comment: Your question implies that the numbers that you test against will be either positive or negative, but `sign` produces _three_ possible answers -1, 0 and 1.   Will your inputs _never_ be zero

Answer (score 1):

What's "hard" about "working around the `sign()` function"?

Here are a few options, they most all seem pretty easy, but you can use any that you like.

```
cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf), labels = c("+", "-"))
factor(sign(x), levels = c(-1, 1), labels = c("-", "+"))
ifelse(x < 0, -1, 1)
ifelse(sign(x) == -1, "+", "-")
c("+", "-")[(x < 0) + 1L]
sub("1", "+", sub("-1", "-", sign(x))) # from comments
```

You may want to make sure that the behavior for a 0 input is what you want/expect.

---

Now optimization probably doesn't matter much on this, because it's hard to imagine that this is a code bottleneck, and even the slower ways to do it from above are pretty quick, but for general education purposes, we can compare the methods:

```
n = 1000
x = runif(n, min = -1, max = 1)

print(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    cut = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf), labels = c("+", "-")),
    factor = factor(sign(x), levels = c(-1, 1), labels = c("-", "+")),
    ifelse_direct = ifelse(x < 0, -1, 1),
    ifelse_sign = ifelse(sign(x) == -1, "+", "-"),
    vector_index = c("+", "-")[(x < 0) + 1L],
    double_sub = sub("1", "+", sub("-1", "-", sign(x))),
    times = 10
), order = "mean")

# Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval  cld
#   vector_index   13.650   14.542   14.9753   15.1135   15.600   16.202    10 a   
#  ifelse_direct   62.070   64.065   83.4343   64.7030   68.473  170.470    10 a   
#    ifelse_sign  193.101  197.737  225.5119  203.9010  209.966  354.551    10  b  
#            cut  189.734  190.560  244.9517  207.7210  240.709  472.329    10  b  
#         factor  514.649  516.468  571.2281  541.8715  553.215  899.395    10   c 
#     double_sub 1295.653 1309.340 1376.3982 1381.7635 1420.775 1502.250    10    d
```

The vector indexing method is probably the least readable, but I included it because I guessed it would be the most efficient, which it is by about 5x. The rest seem to go from simple to complex, unsurprisingly. This isn't entirely fair as the outputs are different classes - if we force everything to be a `factor` the `ifelse_direct` method slows down, but the direct index method is still fastest, now by about 7x.

```
print(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    cut = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf), labels = c("+", "-")),
    factor = factor(sign(x), levels = c(-1, 1), labels = c("-", "+")),
    ifelse_direct = factor(ifelse(x < 0, -1, 1), levels = c("-", "+")),
    ifelse_sign = factor(ifelse(sign(x) == -1, "+", "-"), levels = c("-", "+")),
    vector_index = factor(c("+", "-"), levels = c("-", "+"))[(x < 0) + 1L],
    double_sub = factor(sub("1", "+", sub("-1", "-", sign(x))), levels = c("-", "+")),
    times = 10
), order = "mean")
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval   cld
#   vector_index   22.968   24.742   29.5399   26.5030   33.719   41.736    10 a    
#    ifelse_sign  205.342  206.831  214.7748  211.4585  217.641  237.253    10  b   
#            cut  203.333  228.458  242.2857  234.2420  255.290  324.423    10  b   
#         factor  516.720  519.264  539.4255  524.8190  541.624  609.298    10   c  
#  ifelse_direct  568.426  570.917  575.7954  573.8430  577.363  599.899    10    d 
#     double_sub 1316.820 1320.598 1333.2738 1326.0780 1343.518 1363.342    10     e
```

Comment: Not to mention that if you add the built-in `sign(x)` function to the benchmarks it's around 4 times faster than `vector_index`!